# How to replace a character in the index of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code where I try to replace the **`.`** with a **`-`** in the index of the dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': [0, 1], 'col2': [2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=["abcd", "def.g"])
df.index = df.index.str.replace('.', '-')
df
```

And the output is:

```
    col1    col2
abcd    0   2
def-g   1   3
```

But when doing this, I get the following warning:

```
python\python37\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:5: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will *not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.
  """
```

What is the correct way of replacing a character in the index of a Pandas dataframe without getting this warning?

Comment: Add, `regex=False` when `replace`ing?

Comment: @BigBen Yes, it does solve it! Would you be able to put it in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I literally copied the entire warning line to a search engine and it gave that result as the first result. For your information.